# What will happen to ongoing downloads when we are switching from 3g to wi-fi?

Tags: android, wifimanager

If i am downloading something using 3g. At that time, if i switch from 3g to WiFi, what will happen to ongoing downloads. Will they interrupted?
If they are interrupted, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It will now interrupt on that type of things, you should just have to wait for connection.
and you can check for download completion if its.

I think you have another problem in your code.

Answer (score -1):

if you are turning off 3g first and then enabling wifi, the downloads will get interrupted due to loss of data connectivity during the switch.

But if you turn the wifi on first and assuming that u get connected to a wifi network immediately and then u disconnect 3g then its no issue..